# How to switch images in a C# WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml

I am trying to make an application that switches between an image of the heads sign of a coin and the tails side of a coin. However, every time I press either the "heads" button or the "tails" button, an error occurs. How can I fix my code so that the image successfully switches?

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="HeadsOrTails.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HeadsOrTails"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Image 
        x:Name="coinImage"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Height="100"
        Margin="43,10,374,209"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Width="100"
        Loaded="Image_Loaded"/>
    <Button x:Name="tailsButton" Content="Show Tails" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="40" Margin="190,214,197,65" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="130" Click="tailsButton_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="headsButton" Content="Show Heads" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="40" Margin="43,214,344,65" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="130" Click="headsButton_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="exitButton" Content="Exit" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="40" Margin="339,214,48,65" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="130" Click="exitButton_Click"/>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Media;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace HeadsOrTails
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Image_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void tailsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //create a second bitmap image (tails)
        BitmapImage c = new BitmapImage();
        c.BeginInit();
        c.UriSource = new Uri(@"C:\Users\Raymond\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\HeadsOrTails\tails.jpg");
        c.EndInit();

        var image = sender as Image;
        image.Source = c;
    }

    private void headsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //create the new bitmap image (heads)
        BitmapImage b = new BitmapImage();
        b.BeginInit();
        b.UriSource = new Uri(@"C:\Users\Raymond\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\HeadsOrTails\heads.jpg");
        b.EndInit();

        var image = sender as Image;
        image.Source = b;
    }

    private void exitButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question to indicate what error you are getting?

Comment: As a note, do not use Margins for element layout. Instead, define rows and columns in the Grid, and use nested layout controls, like e.g. a StackPanel with Buttons in a Grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the `sender` argument, because that's the Button, not the Image control.

Use the `coinImage` member instead:

```
private void headsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    coinImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Users\Raymond Karrenbauer\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\HeadsOrTails\heads.jpg"));
}

private void tailsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    coinImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Users\Raymond Karrenbauer\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\HeadsOrTails\tails.jpg"));
}
```

---

Besides that, you should add both image files to your Visual Studio project, set their `Build Action` to `Resource` and access them by a [Resource File Pack URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx). This way you wouldn't have to deal with absolute file paths:

```
private void headsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    coinImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/heads.jpg"));
}

private void tailsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    coinImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/tails.jpg"));
}
```

---

You may then also add the BitmapImages as XAML Resources:

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="heads" UriSource="heads.png"/>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="tails" UriSource="tails.png"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    ...
</Window>
```

And use them like this:

```
private void headsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    coinImage.Source = (ImageSource)Resources["heads"];
}

private void tailsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    coinImage.Source = (ImageSource)Resources["tails"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Clemens is absolutely right, and his second alternative is far superior because it doesn't re-load the bitmaps each time you flip them. However if I may suggest an even better alternative (IMHO) to what you're doing, instead of changing the `Source` of the `coinImage` each time, you might instead want to have two `Image`s, for example, `coinHeadsImage` and `coinTailsImage`, and flip their respective `Visibility` properties in those `Click` handlers. Wrap both `Image`s in their own common `Grid` so that they are overlapping in the visual tree. I'm not 100% certain, but I believe changing the `Visibility` of the `Images` would be more efficient speed-wise than setting the `Source` property, and either way, it would be better architecture because you could bind the `Visibility` properties directly to a hypothetical `IsHeads` property in your code-behind or view model, using appropriate converters of course.

Also, any time you use the `as` syntax, you generally should check the result for `null`. Unlike a simple type cast, you won't get an exception if the object cannot covert to the desired type when you use `as`. Had you checked for `null` you would have caught your error there.

Comment: BitmapImages loaded from URIs are cached by default, so there is no re-loading.

Comment: Is that true even if they're loaded from a disk path? Was not aware of that.

Comment: Not sure, but loading from Pack URIs should be cached. Besides that, having two Image controls with only one visible is a bad approach, IMO. Performance really doesn't matter here. Having a view model may of course be something worth to mention, but then there should be an ImageSource property that the Image.Source property is bound to, and that is changed by a command. That's quite a bit of code for such a simple problem.